# Ajax file upload rails + Rack RawUpload + Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, ajax-upload

I am trying to get ajax image uploading working in my rails app.  I am using Paperclip for the normal image uploading, and that works fine, but I can't seem to get the ajax method hooked up. I am using the Rack RawUpload and the
[File Uploader](https://github.com/valums/file-uploader) plugin.  I followed the general instructions [here](http://marc-bowes.com/2011/08/17/drag-n-drop-upload.html), but I am stuck at the actually attaching the image to the new object on create.  Here is my Controller code:

```
@bottle = Bottle.new(params[:bottle])
    @bottle.user_id = current_user.id
#file = params[:qqfile].is_a?(ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile) ? params[:qqfile] : params[:file]
is_qq = params.has_key?(:qqfile)

if is_qq
    params[:bottle][:image] = params.delete(:file)
    render :json => { "success" => true }
else
        respond_to do |format|
            if @bottle.save
                    format.html { redirect_to '/bottles', notice: 'Bottle was successfully created.' }
                    format.json { render json: @bottle, status: :created, location: @bottle }
            else
                    format.html { render action: "new" }
                    format.json { render json: @bottle.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
        end
    end
```

and Here is the view code:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@bottle, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>

    <div class="form-inputs">
        <%= f.input :brand, :placeholder => 'Brand', :label => false %>
        <%= f.input :region, :placeholder => 'Region', :label => false %>
        <%= f.input :age, :collection => 5..35, :prompt => "Bottle Age", :label => false %>
        <%= f.input :price, :placeholder => 'Price', :label => false, :as => :currency, :input_html => { :class => 'span2' } %>
        <%= f.input :image_id, :as => :hidden %>
        <%= f.text_area :notes, :placeholder => 'Tasting notes...', :size => "160x5"  %>
    </div>  
</div>
<div class="span3 offset2">
Drag a file from your desktop here...
    <div class="well" height="105" style="width:200px;height:300px;">
    <!-- <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" alt="" class="temp_image"> -->
        <div id="file-uploader"></div>
    </div>
    or...
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
</div>
<div class="span8 offset2">
    <%= f.button :submit, :class => 'btn-primary' %>
    &nbsp;
    <%= link_to bottles_path, :class => 'btn btn-danger' do %>
        Cancel
    <% end %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

I am uploading with the File Uploader like this:

```
var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
debug: false,

/* Do not use the jQuery selector here */
element: document.getElementById("file-uploader"),

action: '/bottles',

allowedExtensions: ["jpg", "png"],

/*
 * This uploads via browser memory. 1 MB example.
 */
sizeLimit: 1048576,

/* Set Article category on submit */
onSubmit: function(id, fileName) {
  uploader.setParams({
    authenticity_token: $("input[name='authenticity_token']").attr("value")
  });
},
onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON){
    url = responseJSON.image.image.url;
    $('.well').html('<img src="'+url+'" />');
    $('input#bottle_image_id').val(responseJSON.image.id);
}
```

});

It seems to upload using Rack fine and it passes the :file param to the method, but I can't assign param[:bottle][:image] with the param[:file], i get error:

```
undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
So I am able to get the ajax upload to hook into the paperclip upload and add the appropriate parameters, but now I need to update that same object when I submit the rest of the form, not create a new object.  How can I store the object created by the ajax upload that contains all the image content and update it once the full form is submitted?

EDIT 2:
The error i get when saving is

```
undefined method `save' for #<ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess:0x007ff961d08e48>
```

Which I assume is because I am taking the form data and trying to put it in the same @bottle object and the hashes are not matching up.

Answer (score 0):

I patch lib/rack/request.rb at 217 line to solve this problem

replace

```
{}
```

with

```
@env["rack.request.form_hash"] || {}
```